# user is redirected to wrong page after signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails application with a mechanism to remember the request.url and redirect the user there after they sign in. If there is no request.url (i.e. if they are simply signing in from the root), they should be sent to "/home". However, they keep getting sent to "/courses".

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
def sign_in(user)
  remember_token = User.new_remember_token
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
  user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
  self.current_user = user
end

def redirect_back_or(default)
  p session[:return_to].to_s
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  self.current_user = nil
end

def store_location
  p request.url # I put this here to debug it
  session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]) && user.confirmed?
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or root_url
  elsif
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

**routes.rb** (relevant ones)

```
root 'static_pages#home'

get 'home', to: 'users#home'

get 'signin', to: 'sessions#new'
delete 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

get 'courses', to: 'course#index'
```

At the stage where I do `p request.url`, the terminal outputs "localhost:3000/courses". However, the user is not requesting /courses anywhere during the sign in flow. They simply go to the signin_path, enter their credentials and click 'sign in'.

Why is the request.url being set to /courses?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is silly, but it started working as expected after I closed the browser (Chrome) and opened it back.